# Error while automating python script connecting to oracle via shell script .bat file

Tags: python, oracle, shell, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run my python script using windows cmd line.The script is running fine from jupyter where it is connecting to oracle db.

I am getting the following error while connecting to oracle via python using .bat script

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 32-bit Oracle Client library: "C:\oracle\instantclient_12_1\oci.dll is not the correct architecture". 
See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help
```

The same python script is running fine when I am running via anaconda.

Here's my .bat script which I am running

```
python -m pip install cx_Oracle

"C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" "C:\Users\abc\script1.py"
```

Comment: Are you running a 64 bit OS?

Comment: yes-I'm using 64 bit os on windows

Comment: How do you know that the `python.exe` used for installing cxOracle is the same as the `python.exe` one used to run script1.py? What is the output of the command `where python`?

Comment: Do you have both versions of python i.e 32 bit and 64 bit?. From your running command it seems python.exe is 32 bit and instant client is 64 bit.

Comment: I agree that checking that Python and the Oracle Client libraries have the same 32- or 64-bitness is the first step.  After that, you could try setting the PATH environment variable in the script to include the Oracle client library directory.

Comment: @ChristopherJones : how can I find oracle client library path ?

Comment: It's where ever you installed it!  Check https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html